# Apply javascript to multiple items by class

Tags: javascript

I have some select boxes that I want to have color coded. There are three per row, by 18 rows.

It is easy to color code the drop down, but I need to use Javascript to color code the display of the selected item.  I have cobbled together a script that does it, but only for the first one on the page .. and it changes ALL of them to the same color.  I need the script to apply to each one independently.  I am very much a beginner at Javascript.  I have figured out that I need to use the var i thing, but I can't get it to work.

```
<td>
    <div>
        <select type="" name="tee_condition" class="selectcondition"  id="tee_condition">
            <option style="color: #5cb85c;"  value="Excellent"<?php if($listresult['tee_condition'] == 'Excellent'){echo 'selected';} ?> >Excellent</option>
            <option style="color: #0275d8;" value="Good"<?php if($listresult['tee_condition'] == 'Good'){echo 'selected';} ?> >Good</option>
            <option style="color: #f0ad4e;" value="Fair"<?php if($listresult['tee_condition'] == 'Fair'){echo 'selected';} ?> >Fair</option>
            <option style="color: #ff0000;" value="Poor"<?php if($listresult['tee_condition'] == 'Poor'){echo 'selected';} ?> >Poor</option>                                    
        </select>                                               
    </div>
</td>
<td class="text-center">
    <div>
        <select type="" name="fairway_condition" class="selectcondition"  id="fairway_condition">
            <option style="color: #5cb85c;"  value="Excellent"<?php if($listresult['fairway_condition'] == 'Excellent'){echo 'selected';} ?> >Excellent</option>
            <option style="color: #0275d8;" value="Good"<?php if($listresult['fairway_condition'] == 'Good'){echo 'selected';} ?> >Good</option>
            <option style="color: #f0ad4e;" value="Fair"<?php if($listresult['fairway_condition'] == 'Fair'){echo 'selected';} ?> >Fair</option>
            <option style="color: #ff0000;" value="Poor"<?php if($listresult['fairway_condition'] == 'Poor'){echo 'selected';} ?> >Poor</option>                                    
        </select>                                               
    </div>
</td>
<td class="text-center">                                                
    <div>
        <select type="" name="green_condition" class="selectcondition"  id="green_condition">
            <option style="color: #5cb85c;"  value="Excellent"<?php if($listresult['green_condition'] == 'Excellent'){echo 'selected';} ?> >Excellent</option>
            <option style="color: #0275d8;" value="Good"<?php if($listresult['green_condition'] == 'Good'){echo 'selected';} ?> >Good</option>
            <option style="color: #f0ad4e;" value="Fair"<?php if($listresult['green_condition'] == 'Fair'){echo 'selected';} ?> >Fair</option>
            <option style="color: #ff0000;" value="Poor"<?php if($listresult['green_condition'] == 'Poor'){echo 'selected';} ?> >Poor</option>                                  
        </select>                                               
    </div>
</td>
```

And my javascript is:

```
    //**** Script to Color the Dropdowns
$(document).ready(function () {
    colorSelect(); // call this first so we start out with the correct Color
    // this will call our function every time the selection value of the field changes
    $(".selectcondition").change(function () {
        colorSelect();
    });

});
// this changes the color of the selected item
function colorSelect() {
    if ($(".selectcondition").val() === "Excellent"){
        $('.selectcondition').css('color','#5cb85c');
    }else if($(".selectcondition").val() === "Good"){
        $('.selectcondition').css('color','#0275d8');
    }else if($(".selectcondition").val() === "Fair"){
        $('.selectcondition').css('color','#f0ad4e');
    }else {
        $('.selectcondition').css('color','#FF0000');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.css` will set the CSS of *all* matching elements. Iterate over the selects with `each` instead, and get a reference to the current one you're iterating over with `this`.

You can also make the code much more concise by using an object indexed by option values instead of repetitive `if`/`else` statements:

```js
function colorSelect() {
  const colors = {
    Excellent: '#5cb85c',
    Good: '#0275d8',
    Fair: '#f0ad4e',
    Poor: '#FF0000'
  }
  $(".selectcondition").each(function() {
    $(this).css('color', colors[this.value]);
  });
}
colorSelect();
$(".selectcondition").change(colorSelect);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <div>
    <select type="" name="tee_condition" class="selectcondition" id="tee_condition">
      <option style="color: #5cb85c;" value="Excellent" <?php if($listresult[ 'tee_condition']=='Excellent' ){echo 'selected';} ?> >Excellent</option>
      <option style="color: #0275d8;" value="Good" <?php if($listresult[ 'tee_condition']=='Good' ){echo 'selected';} ?> >Good</option>
      <option style="color: #f0ad4e;" value="Fair" <?php if($listresult[ 'tee_condition']=='Fair' ){echo 'selected';} ?> >Fair</option>
      <option style="color: #ff0000;" value="Poor" <?php if($listresult[ 'tee_condition']=='Poor' ){echo 'selected';} ?> >Poor</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</td>
<td class="text-center">
  <div>
    <select type="" name="fairway_condition" class="selectcondition" id="fairway_condition">
      <option style="color: #5cb85c;" value="Excellent" <?php if($listresult[ 'fairway_condition']=='Excellent' ){echo 'selected';} ?> >Excellent</option>
      <option style="color: #0275d8;" value="Good" <?php if($listresult[ 'fairway_condition']=='Good' ){echo 'selected';} ?> >Good</option>
      <option style="color: #f0ad4e;" value="Fair" <?php if($listresult[ 'fairway_condition']=='Fair' ){echo 'selected';} ?> >Fair</option>
      <option style="color: #ff0000;" value="Poor" <?php if($listresult[ 'fairway_condition']=='Poor' ){echo 'selected';} ?> >Poor</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</td>
<td class="text-center">
  <div>
    <select type="" name="green_condition" class="selectcondition" id="green_condition">
      <option style="color: #5cb85c;" value="Excellent" <?php if($listresult[ 'green_condition']=='Excellent' ){echo 'selected';} ?> >Excellent</option>
      <option style="color: #0275d8;" value="Good" <?php if($listresult[ 'green_condition']=='Good' ){echo 'selected';} ?> >Good</option>
      <option style="color: #f0ad4e;" value="Fair" <?php if($listresult[ 'green_condition']=='Fair' ){echo 'selected';} ?> >Fair</option>
      <option style="color: #ff0000;" value="Poor" <?php if($listresult[ 'green_condition']=='Poor' ){echo 'selected';} ?> >Poor</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</td>
```